# Spring RestTemplate - What does a ResponseBody Class look like

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate, lombok

I have a really simple rest client and I would like to parse the service response into a custom ResponseBody Class:

```
ResponseEntity<CustomResponseBody> entity = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, CustomResponseBody.class);
```

The actual question is how the CustomResponseBody class should look like, in terms of setters, getters and constructors assuming that the output from the service I am consuming is a JSON like:

```
{item1:something, item2:otherthing}
```

And my makeRestTemplate method is:

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate makeRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
    for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
        if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = makeObjectMapper();
            jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
            jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("application", "json", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET),
                    new MediaType("text", "javascript", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET)));
        }
    }

    return restTemplate;
}
```

I had it working with the lombok's anotation @Data but I would like to know what is the minimal requirement of the customResponseBody Class to actually parse the response.

UPDATE:

A simple POJO does the job, I had some problems trying to implement custom setter and getter methods, it looks like anything beside plain getter and setter methods makes the binding process fail.

Accepted

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class CustomResponseBody {
    private String item1;
    private String item2;
}
```

Unaccepted

```
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomResponseBody {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String item1;

    @Getter
    private String item2;

    public void setItem2(String item2) {
        if ("something".equals(item2)) {
            this.item2 = "whatever";
        } else {
            this.item2 = "otherstuff"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple POJO implements Serializable,  pre-enabled  HttpMessageConverters should be able to convert any Serializable POJO based on your Content-Type in Headers.

Answer (score 0):

If the json is {"item1":value1,"item2":value2} and you just want the two values, then your mapping pojo should have two fields, "item1" and "item2" with the same types as value1 and value2. Default setters and getters should be fine.